# can not see my heroku remotes after cloning git repo

Tags: git, heroku

I had 3 remotes:

- origin (default)
- heroku-server
- heroku-client

After cloning the repo on another computer and run `git remote` I can only see `origin`. Any ideas?

Comment: When you clone a remote repository, the default remote `origin` is the alias of the path/url to the remote repository. The other remotes are created manually or by other tools. For example, by `git remote add heroku-server <url_to_heroku_server>`.

Comment: alright, so if I clone repo to a new machine I have to always add these remotes manually?